# How can I force LTspice to redraw a plot during a long simulation?

Tags: simulation, ltspice

Sometimes during long simulations, the LTspice plot window will display a yellow "broken" icon, and/or simply not render parts or all of the data. Sometimes the axis are missing, sometimes it only shows the most recent data.

Once it finishes, it will redraw correctly, and do so every time you select a new signal. But during an ongoing simulation, you're just looking at a blank/broken plot window.

Is there a way to redraw the window without interrupting the simulation?

Comment: If you're talking about the Windows version, none of what you say sounds familiar to me. Some screenshots would be useful.

Comment: Have you tried zoom to fit?

Comment: What operating system are you using? I've never seen this behaviour under Windoze.

Comment: I'm running it under Wine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Control Panel > Waveforms > Hot Keys > Waveform > Redraw Window (Choose Hotkey)

Have similar problems with LTC in wine.
Note; it wont reload the file from disk, only reload it visually from ram